# Snowflake terraform Error: 002043 (02000): SQL compilation error: Object does not exist, or operation cannot be performed

Tags: terraform, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I had the code below.

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    snowflake = {
      source  = "chanzuckerberg/snowflake"
      version = "0.22.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "snowflake" {
  alias = "sys_admin"
  role  = "SYSADMIN"
  username = "tf-snow"
  private_key_path = "..."
  region = "ap-southeast-2"
  account = "..."

}

resource "snowflake_warehouse" "star_warehouse" {
  provider       = snowflake.sys_admin
  name           = "STAR_WAREHOUSE"
  warehouse_size = "XSmall"

  auto_suspend = 60
}

resource "snowflake_database" "STAR_DB" {
  provider = snowflake.sys_admin
  name     = "STAR_DB"
}

resource "snowflake_schema" "public" {
  provider            = snowflake.sys_admin
  database            = "STAR_DB"
  name                = "public"
  data_retention_days = 1
}

resource "snowflake_table" "sales" {
  provider            = snowflake.sys_admin
  database            = "STAR_DB"
  schema              = "public"
  name                = "sales"

  column {
    name     = "id"
    type     = "int"
  }
}
```

and I decided to rename "STAR_DB" to be the lowercase "star_db".

Now, no matter what I do, I keep getting this error.

```
Error: 002043 (02000): SQL compilation error: Object does not exist, or operation cannot be performed.
with snowflake_schema.public
on snowflake.tf line 33, in resource "snowflake_schema" "public":
```

```
Error: 002043 (02000): SQL compilation error: Object does not exist, or operation cannot be performed.
with snowflake_table.sales
on snowflake.tf line 40, in resource "snowflake_table" "sales":
```

I reverted the code, I remove huge parts of it, I deleted the underlying resources and then recreated them but still the same error.

Anyone know what's going on?

Note: I am using terraform cloud

Comment: I'm going to go on a limb here: I feel that it can't delete the DB as it is not aware that  it should delete the tables and schemas first. What I don't like about this provider is that I don't see any attributes being exported after creation so that means you can use only explicit dependencies. In other words, try with `depends_on = [snowflake_database.STAR_DB]` in both  `snowflake_schema` and `snowflake_table`.

Comment: Doesn't seem to help unfortunately, even if I remove the file itself it doesn't help. I have a bunch of AWS configuration in other files, I have to go through and delete it all manually and start again. This is a really bad bug.

Comment: Yeah, I would submit an issue for the provider in their Github repo.

Comment: Just did it, thanks for the help anyway

Comment: I put  depends_on = [snowflake_schema.public] on the table and it removed one of the errors! Oddly putting depends_on = [snowflake_database.STAR_DB] on the schema doesn't remove the other error. Curious.

Comment: Yeah, it now comes down to hitting the right order. :) Maybe terraform graph could help. :)

Comment: Or maybe it depends on the warehouse resource?

Comment: doesn't seem to work. I've tried 
[snowflake_database.STAR_DB]
[snowflake_warehouse.star_warehouse]
[snowflake_warehouse.star_warehouse, snowflake_database.STAR_DB]

I also tried permutations of 
[snowflake_warehouse.star_warehouse, snowflake_database.STAR_DB, snowflake_schema.public] on the table to see if that would help. No luck yet.

Comment: also tried making database depend_on warehouse.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I logged an issue here.
https://github.com/chanzuckerberg/terraform-provider-snowflake/issues/892

And found out that renaming between lowercase and uppercase causes mapping issues in snowflake.

What I did in the end was I just deleted the resources from the state file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue before; when you have resources that depend on each other, like a database and a schema, it's best practice to reference their dependencies. Here it'd be better if you referenced your database name inside your table and schema blocks instead of adding it as a string.

Here when you change the name of the database, Terraform deletes the old one and creates a new one (you can verify this by running `terraform plan`); however, since the name has been added without a reference, your Schema and Table won't be aware of the change and give you the above error. This is what I mean by referencing your dependencies:

```
resource "snowflake_database" "STAR_DB" {
  provider = snowflake.sys_admin
  name     = "STAR_DB"
}

resource "snowflake_schema" "public" {
  provider            = snowflake.sys_admin
  database            = snowflake_database.STAR_DB.name     
  name                = "public"
  data_retention_days = 1
}

resource "snowflake_table" "sales" {
  provider            = snowflake.sys_admin
  database            = snowflake_database.STAR_DB.name
  schema              = snowflake_schema.public.name
  name                = "sales"

  column {
    name     = "id"
    type     = "int"
  }
}
```

Let me know if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem after renaming a DB.
I solved by changing something on dbt_project.yml (add a space or whatever). That kind of reset dbt configuration and reads again profiles.yml with correct DB name

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).